# how to change default delete icon of odoo 11

Tags: odoo-11

I have given editable bottom so i am getting default delete icon of odoo11. But i want to change it only to my module. How to change the delete icon to my own module ?

```
 <field name="name"> Attachments</field>

 <field name="model">attachments</field>    

 <field name="arch" type="xml">

 <form string="Attachments">

 <field name="line_ids" >

    <tree string="Attachments" editable="bottom">

          <field name="description" />

           <field name="file_name" invisible="1" />

          <field name="upload_file" filename="file_name" />

            <button name ="download" icon ="gtk-go-down" type="object" />

       </tree>

    </field>
```

Thanks in Advance !

Comment: By module, do you want to say model(attachments) ?

Comment: yes to my model attachments

Comment: Actually delete icon is coming as warning icon there so i want to change that.

Comment: Odoo use Dustin as delete icon, please check your code & diff. Moreover please use font awesome icon for your download button.

Answer (score 1):

just add `delete="false"` in tree view

```
<field name="name">Attachments</field>
<field name="model">attachments</field>    
<field name="arch" type="xml">
<form string="Attachments">
<field name="line_ids" >
    <tree string="Attachments" editable="bottom" delete="false">
      <field name="description" />
       <field name="file_name" invisible="1" />
       <field name="upload_file" filename="file_name" />
       <button name ="download" icon ="gtk-go-down" type="object" />
   </tree>
</field>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add **delete="false"** in tree tag
ex.

```
<tree string="Attachments" editable="bottom" delete="false">

          <field name="description" />

           <field name="file_name" invisible="1" />

          <field name="upload_file" filename="file_name" />

            <button name ="download" icon ="gtk-go-down" type="object" />

       </tree>
```